# What is a good criterion for naming theorems/conjectures/lemmas?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-modeling

Wikipedia, proofwiki, planetmath, and many others have various ways of naming theorems (and proofs and conjectures). I'm making a similar project, and am trying to create a searchable database of theorems. However, to be able to search for a theorem, one needs to have some kind of indexing procedure. Common methods seem to be:

- Do a search for terms that was searched in theorems (a google type search). This works but doesn't give titles to theorems.
- Search for names of theorems. This sometimes works but often theorems don't have names.
- Have a tree of topics ("namespaces" of sorts), and insert theorems inside there.
- Traverse the dependency of theorems on other theorems.
- Look at large lists of theorems in some category and find the ones that you are looking for.
- Name theorems based on the papers that they occurred in (Theorem 2.2 of __)
- Name theorems with a short informal sentence that conveys the idea the proof is trying to capture

I would prefer to be able to name each theorem (or proof or conjecture or etc.) with some unique meaningful label. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: The penultimate suggestion seems the most promising (at first sight, at least), because you can construct relatively short but still meaningful keys by concatenating: (1) a code for a publication, such as a journal, or an existing database of papers, such as arXiv.org; (2) a short key to identify a unique paper within the publication, using its native format, whatever that might be (easy in the case of arXiv.org); (3) perhaps simply a numerical index to the theorem within the paper (ignoring its own internal numbering system, for simplicity, although you could store such references in the DB).

Comment: Perhaps something like the Resource Description Framework (see e.g. Wikipedia) is relevant? I don't know anything about it myself. Sorry to comment twice in such quick succession!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a reasonable answer to this, in case anyone else is interested.

All problem (theorem/corollary/etc.) statements seem to be of the form:

There exists $x \in S$ s.t. $P(x)=True$, where $P$ is some predicate, or

For all $x \in S$, $P(x)=True$, where $P$ is some predicate.

Thus the short hand can be a set, relation, property kind of thing (there's lots of edge cases I could go on about but this is the idea).

Comment: This is a very poor method, because most theorems can be stated in many ways. Additionally, though not catastrophically, some theorems require multiple layers of quantification. Depending on what formal language you're using, your assertion might not be true as well.

Comment: Yes and no. Once you allow definitions (so grouping of symbols into "shorthand"), this becomes much more reasonable. I'm also not using a formal language (instead breaking everything into topics, problems, definitions, and solutions, then connecting things via pre and post-reqs), so there is room for the informal shorthand that occurs in practice.

Comment: (also, the predicate can be a not of something and allow it to equal false instead. I'm providing shorthand (so you can say there does not exist and such) but this is the general idea). Is the fact that they can be stated in many ways a bad thing too? There can be multiple equivalent statements and then have them linked together, which I think would work decently. This is all very high level and I've thought through this more in depth than this but it's probably not worth discussing all the minute details.